# how to get organized Dict sorted by keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, for-loop

I want to sort a list of dict by key list

```
 values = [{"a":25},{"b":31},{"c":78},{"a":17},{"b":74},{"c":44},  {"a":14},{"c":2}]
 keys = ["a","b","c"]
 sorted_values = [{k: v for d in values[i:i+len(keys)] for k, v in d.items()} for i in range(0, len(values), len(keys))]
```

This the result when i loop using the actual code :

```
 {'a': 25, 'b': 31, 'c': 78}
 {'a': 17, 'b': 74, 'c': 44}
 {'a': 14, 'c': 2}
```

I want in the end to have this:

```
 {'a': 25, 'b': 31, 'c': 78}
 {'a': 17, 'b': 74, 'c': 44}
 {'a': 14,'b':'' ,'c': 2}
```



Comment: Sorry, what's the difference here? Is it only the last `b`?

Comment: @JammyDodger  yes exactly i want to add "b" and i get the same length always

Comment: Can't you just add `{'b':''}` to the initial list?

Comment: No in my case i can't adding elements , because data is taken from the parsing of  docx document

Comment: A slightly manual solution would be to iterate through each dict, check for each key and insert if missing

Comment: What if the first b were missing? What if the first b were before the first a?

Comment: These parsing rules won't work. If a value can be missing, it might not be in the last object. The chunks don't work if a value can be missing in the middle.

Comment: @KennyOstrom exactly i have some missing value in the middle, as result the chunk's  don't work

Comment: @dhifallahothmen Are the keys in `values` always in the same order? Because if they can be in **any** order, *and* there are missing values, there will be no unambiguous way to parse the data. For example, in the sequence `c, b, a, b, c`, would `a` belong to the first group, or the second group?

Comment: Can we get an answer on the order of the keys within each record? We need something that's guaranteed, or the error rate could get high.

Comment: @KennyOstrom the order is like what i have in my list keys (keys = ["a","b","c"] )

Answer (score 1):

Are you alright with an O(n) traversal after the fact to correct your data?

```
values = [{"a":25},{"b":31},{"c":78},{"a":17},{"b":74},{"c":44},  {"a":14},{"c":2}]
keys = ["a","b","c"]
sorted_values = [{k: v for d in values[i:i+len(keys)] for k, v in d.items()} for i in range(0, len(values), len(keys))]
for k in sorted_values: 
    if not k.get("b"):
        k["b"] = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keys list is fixed you can just post process the dict like so:

```
values = [{"a":25},{"b":31},{"c":78},{"a":17},{"b":74},{"c":44},  {"a":14},{"c":2}]
keys = ["a","b","c"]
sorted_values = [{k: v for d in values[i:i+len(keys)] for k, v in d.items()} for i in range(0, len(values), len(keys))]

# Post processing. Fill up missing values with empty strings.
for d in sorted_values:
    for key in keys:
        d[key] = d.get(key, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are chunking on the number of keys, but that is not reliable. The existance of a key is not reliable. However the order is.

Here is a generator function which parses the dict values and puts them in an accumulator until we identify the end of a record. We identify the start of a new record record by either duplicating a key or getting a key out of sequence (from the order in the original values list).

I have created a new input dataset which has multiple missing keys, to simulate as many things that can go wrong as I could manage. Also, all the values are just their record number to make it easier to see if the output is correct. I'm happy to add more test cases, although we may still have inputs that cannot be parsed unambiguously. It really should be fixed at the other end (although that's not in the scope of the question).

```
values = [
    {"a":1}, {"b":1}, {"c":1},
    {"b":2}, {"c":2}, 
    {"a":3}, {"c":3},
    {"a":4}, {"b":4}, {"c":4},
    {"a":5}, {"b":5},
    {"a":6}, {"b":6}, {"c":6},
]
keys = ["a","b","c"]

def parse(values):
    accumulator = {}
    key_index = 0
    for value in values:
        for k, v in value.items():
            try:
                new_index = keys.index(k)

                repeat_key = k in accumulator
                sequence_error = key_index > new_index
                if accumulator and (repeat_key or sequence_error):
                    yield accumulator
                    key_index = 0
                    accumulator = {}

                accumulator[k] = v
                key_index = new_index
            except:
                pass
    yield accumulator

for doc in parse(values):
    print(doc)
```

> {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}
>   {'b': 2, 'c': 2}
>   {'a': 3, 'c': 3}
>   {'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'c': 4}
>   {'a': 5, 'b': 5}
>   {'a': 6, 'b': 6, 'c': 6}

To add default values, you can preinitialize them in the accumulator, or just apply them afterwards

```
def apply_defaults(doc, default_value = ''):
    replacement = {}
    for k in keys:
        if k in doc:
            replacement[k] = doc[k]
        else:
            replacement[k] = default_value
    return replacement

for doc in parse(values):
    print(apply_defaults(doc))
```

Comment: An example of errors we can't parse, first record has (a, b) second record has only (c). There's no possible way to detect that with this input definition, so we'll just not worry about it.

Comment: This can be done a lot more simply if you assume each value contains at least one key from `keys`, and ignore all other keys. (IOW, just take the example input at face value and pretend there's no ambiguities).

Comment: How so? This is already a simple heuristic, and I am already ignoring keys not in keys.

Comment: Use a moving window to walk along the list of values, whilst repeatedly iterating over the keys to create each group (filling in gaps wherever necessary). It should only need about a dozen lines of code to achieve that.

Comment: PS: when I said "ignore all other keys", that was intended to deal with ambiguous values like this: `{'b': 1, 'c': 9}`. IOW, always take *at most* one matching item from each value.

Comment: No way -- if multiple keys are in the input, we have to include them. We don't want this to break (too badly) if someone fixes the data source (where the real problem is).

Comment: Actually, I contradicted myself by giving that value with multiple keys, because my initial comment was based on taking the OP's example at face value. Anyway, I managed to write a ten-line function that satisfies my original assumptions, so I'll just leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood OP right, but this script will "fill" the gaps with default values:

```
values = [
    {"a":1}, {"b":1}, {"c":1},
    {"a":2},
    {"a":3},          {"c":3},
    {"a":4}, {"b":4}, {"c":4},
    {"a":5}, {"b":5},
    {"a":6}, {"b":6}, {"c":6},
                      {"c":9},
]
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']

from itertools import cycle

c, i = cycle(map(lambda k: {k: ''}, keys)), iter(values)
current_value, current_dummy = next(i), next(c)

out, sentinel = [], object()
while True:
    v1 = [*current_value.keys()][0]
    v2 = [*current_dummy.keys()][0]

    if (v1 == v2):
        out.append(current_value)
        current_value = next(i, {sentinel:0})
    else:
        out.append(current_dummy)
    current_dummy = next(c).copy()

    if [*current_value.keys()][0] is sentinel and [*current_dummy.keys()][0] == keys[0]:
        break

for item in out:
    print(item)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': 1}
{'b': 1}
{'c': 1}
{'a': 2}
{'b': ''}
{'c': ''}
{'a': 3}
{'b': ''}
{'c': 3}
{'a': 4}
{'b': 4}
{'c': 4}
{'a': 5}
{'b': 5}
{'c': ''}
{'a': 6}
{'b': 6}
{'c': 6}
{'a': ''}
{'b': ''}
{'c': 9}
```

EDIT (Final grouping)

```
#final grouping the `out` list

from itertools import groupby

for v, g in groupby(enumerate(out), lambda k: k[0] // len(keys)):
    print(*[i[1] for i in g])
```

Prints:

```
{'a': 1} {'b': 1} {'c': 1}
{'a': 2} {'b': ''} {'c': ''}
{'a': 3} {'b': ''} {'c': 3}
{'a': 4} {'b': 4} {'c': 4}
{'a': 5} {'b': 5} {'c': ''}
{'a': 6} {'b': 6} {'c': 6}
{'a': ''} {'b': ''} {'c': 9}
```

OR:

```
for v, g in groupby(enumerate(out), lambda k: k[0] // len(keys)):
    d = {}
    for i in g:
        d.update(i[1])
    print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}
{'a': 2, 'b': '', 'c': ''}
{'a': 3, 'b': '', 'c': 3}
{'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'c': 4}
{'a': 5, 'b': 5, 'c': ''}
{'a': 6, 'b': 6, 'c': 6}
{'a': '', 'b': '', 'c': 9}
```

Comment: Your output doesn't look like what the OP asked for in the question.

Comment: @ekhumoro Now with grouping

Comment: Good effort, but it can be done a lot more simply than this.